# how to check if all ajax functions are done loading in the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, sharepoint-2010

In my page I am using SharePoint 2010 client object model to call asynchronous functions (ajax calls). On page load, I make lots of ajax calls to load data. But I would like to know if there is a way so that a function can get called once all the ajax calls are done. 
Is there someway to do this? Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific order to which the ajax calls are fired or are they independent of each other? If so, why can't you just check when the last ajax call reaches its `success` function?

Comment: they are independent, and how would I know which is the last one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A jquery solution, use `$.active` to see how many active requests there are.

So...

```
var ajaxCheckInterval = setInterval(checkAjaxState, 10);

function checkAjaxState(){
    if($.active == 0){
        clearInterval(ajaxCheckInterval);
        // do work
    }
}
```

<s>Possibly something like this:</s>

```
var ajaxCheckInterval = setInterval(checkAjaxState, 10);

function checkAjaxState(){
    if(document.readyState == 'complete'){
        clearInterval(ajaxCheckInterval);
        // do work
    }
}
```

Comment: so if readystate is complete, that means that that the page is not waiting for any more ajax calls, so basically all ajax calls are returned?

Comment: surely `document.readyState` only reflects the main document state, and not whether any AJAX calls are outstanding?

Comment: This is a good solution, yet there is no safe solution. A fail test is when and ajax in contained inside a `setTimeout or setInterval` call.

Comment: @Alnitak - yea i think you're right. I just double checked it with a test.

Comment: @Gabe I checked the W3C specs and can find no native DOM global property that says whether any AJAX requests are outstanding.  jQuery's `ajaxStop` handler works by having jQuery count all pending requests.

Comment: @Gabe not really - `.ajaxStop` (per my answer) is the "right" way of doing it with jQuery rather than polling the state of `$.active`.

Comment: @Alnitak - This is an alternate solution and I am leaving it, yours maybe be ultimately better.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using jQuery to issue the AJAX calls, register an [`ajaxStop`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) handler:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    // this will be called when all running AJAX calls have completed
});
```

Comment: no i am not, I am using sharepoint function `clientContext.executeQueryAsync()`

Comment: @omega then you should tag your question `sharepoint`, because the state you'll be looking for (if it exists) will be there, rather than in jQuery or in the DOM.

Comment: @omega would `clientContext.HasPendingRequest` help?